# EditBox character limitation in android

Tags: android, limit, character, editbox

In my app i have placed some `EditBoxes` . When the user types some data i want to stop him from entering too much of characters. i.e When the number of characters exceed 80, the characters typed next to them must be stopped and it must be invisible.

Is there any option for this in android or should I write a code of my own. If I have to write a code of my own please help me friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setFilters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5b%5d%29) or android:maxLength in xml